# Grabbing URL sans the last segment/file with a regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, unix

Looking for a regex so that I may grab everything BUT the last segment + extension.

So for example

```
http://stackoverflow.com/stuff/code/apple.jpg
```

I need

```
http://stackoverflow.com/stuff/code/
```

I'm able to grab the last segment, but with a myriad of possible directories this images could be under, I'm unsure how to get everything sans the last segment.

Comment: So you want to drop `.com` and `apple.jpg`?

Comment: You have the `unix` tag - does this mean you want something using the Unix tools?

Comment: @ctwheels sorry, typo, leave .com

Comment: @GavinGregory edited my answer.

Comment: @GavinGregory : I've upated my answer as well ;-) . Good luck to all.

Answer (score 0):

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/mnteYB/3)

```
https?:\/{2}.*\/
```

You may even be able to simply use `.*\/` (if you don't need to ensure it starts with `http` or `https`). If that's the case, you may as well just split on the last occurrence of `/` - see second snippet below (it's hidden, so expand it).

```js
var s = "http://stackoverflow.com/stuff/code/apple.jpg"
var r = /https?:\/{2}.*\//

console.log(r.exec(s))
```

Substring on last occurrence method:

```js
var s = "http://stackoverflow.com/stuff/code/apple.jpg"

console.log(s.substr(0, s.lastIndexOf('/')) + '/')
```

---

### Explanation

- `https?` Match `http` or `https` (`s` is made optional by `?`)
- `:\/{2}` Match the colon character `:` literally, followed by two forward slash characters `/` literally
- `.*` Match any character any number of times
- `\/` Match the forward slash character `/` literally

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: i just noticed that you need the trailing `/` char and have updated my answer to meet that requirement. See `#` comment line in code

---

Here's a unix shell solution

```
var="http://stackoverflow.com/stuff/code/apple.jpg"
echo "${var%/*}/"
#--------------^-- we've deleted everything from that  last / to end
#--------------+      just append a replacment char /
```

**output**

```
http://stackoverflow.com/stuff/code/
```

`%` is a parameter expansion feature that removes the smallest suffix pattern.
See [POSIX definitions for Parameter Expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) for detailed info on this and similar features. (Go to the bottom of the page).

IHTH

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to manipulate the string, you can use this to remove the end piece:

```
var str = "http://stackoverflow.com/stuff/code/apple.jpg"
str = str.replace(/\/[^/]+$/, '/')
```

Regex explanation:

- `\/` match a slash
- `[^/]+$` match a string that has no `/` characters in it and continues until the end of the string

This will replace `/apple.jpg` with `/`